# Describe the subgroup of $\mathbb Z_{12}$ generated by $6 \text { and } 9$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11\}$ is $\mathbb Z_{12}$.

$6 + 9 = 3$

$6 + 9 + 6 = 9$

$9 + 6 + 9 = 0$

$9 + 6 + 9 + 6= 6$

So far it looks like $6$ and $9$ generate $\{0, 3, 6, 9\}$. How does one exhaust all the possible  elements generated by $6$ and $9$?

Comment: One thing that makes this easier: $\langle 9\rangle = \{0,9,6,3\}$ and $\langle 6\rangle = \{0,6\}$ so that $\langle 6,9\rangle = \langle 9\rangle$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's denote the subgroup generated by $\bar{6}$ and $\bar{9}$ by $\langle \bar{6}, \bar{9} \rangle$. This way we have an easy way to denote the subgroup. Now let's give the definition of a subgroup generated by some a subset of $G$, our group. In this case $$\langle \bar{6}, \bar{9} \rangle=\{x\in \mathbb{Z}_{12}:x= \bar{6}a+\bar{9}b=\bar{3}(\bar{2}a+\bar{3}b), n\in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$ 
Since $\gcd(\bar{2},\bar{3})=\bar{1}$ we can find integers $a,b$ such that $\bar{2}a+\bar{3}b=\bar{1}$ and our set simplifies to
$$\langle \bar{6}, \bar{9} \rangle=\{x\in \mathbb{Z}_{12}:x=n\bar{3}, n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$ 
So $\langle \bar{6}, \bar{9} \rangle=\langle \bar{3} \rangle$. Which is the set you found.

---

For extreme formality, I have denoted the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ with a bar. This is due to the elements being in fact, equivalence classes. Furthermore, by $nx$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x\in \mathbb{Z}_{12}$ we mean the formal sum $x+x+x+...+x$ counting $n$ elements summed under the operation $+$. Similarly, for $n<0$ we define the equivalent sum but with $(-x)$ terms.

Comment: Technically, it should be: $\sum_j 6a_j + 9b_j$ which amounts to:$\sum_j 3(2a_j + 3b_j)$. Noting that $\gcd(2,3) = 1$, we can pick suitable $a_j,b_j$ so that we get $1$ (mod $12$), which gives us that $3$ generates the subgroup.

Comment: @ Eoin $\langle n \rangle = \{x \in \mathbb Z_n: x = \sum_{i = 0}^n n, n \in N\}$. Is that the general definition of $\langle n \rangle$ for any number of $n$?

Comment: @keys $\langle n\rangle = \{x \in \Bbb Z_n: x = \sum_{i = 0}^k n, k \in \Bbb N\}$ (you don't want to use $n$ for different things in two places). Note that typically, we also need to add "negatives" but for subgroups of *finite* cyclic groups, we can get away with just "non-negatives".

Comment: @ David Wheeler $\langle n \rangle$ is called a cyclic subgroup, but what about $\langle n, m \rangle$? Is it also called cyclic subgroup?

Comment: @keys No. It is the group generated by $2$ elements in this case. You can extend this definition to any finitely generated group however. It turns out that the group generated by $6$ and $9$ is the cyclic subgroup generated by $3$ though.

Comment: @DavidWheeler I was avoiding that since under group laws there is no distributive axiom and the multiplication under group laws is in fact formal summation.

Answer (score 0):

It is the image of the subgroup of $\mathbf Z$ generated by $6$ and $9$ by the canonical morphism $\mathbf Z\rightarrow \mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z$, i.e. the image of the subgroup of $\mathbf Z$ generated by $\gcd(9,12)=(3)$.

Hence in $\mathbf Z\rightarrow \mathbf Z/12\mathbf Z$ we obtain the subgroup generated by $3\bmod 12$.